# Can't get API call results (using fetch), when calling the action via dispatcher of Flux design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, flux

I have a service/store that is making fetch calls to api.
And need to get some data back (projects details) from that service and display it on the component which did the call.

I created a sandbox to illustrate the issue... but without the api cause it's deployed locally. Instead I created some mockups just for the look & feel:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-morning-267l5

The call to getProjects (from ProjectsList component) is performed but getting **undefined** when trying to execute:

```
Actions.getProjects().then((response) => console.log(response));
```

I managed only when making the getProjects method as static inside the RestService (not calling Actions.getProjects, calling ApiService.getProjects)!

But in that case I don't need the whole flux solution with dispatcher! Why it didn't work with flux design?

Comment: My guess would be that the response is not returning JSON content type and it fails to parse. The assumption is made based on the code from the sandbox. Do you see the request in the network tab of the browser?

Comment: I tried making the return inside the first then clause (return response.json()) instead of return data fro mthe second then clause but still the same. And yes I can see the request and I print the data to console from the service... but when reaching the component this is failing: Actions.getProjects().then((response) => console.log(response)); (giving: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined). Isn't related to async calls?

Comment: I managed when making the getProjects method as static inside the RestService (not calling Actions.getProjects, calling ApiService.getProjects)! But in that case I don't need the whole flux solution with dispatcher! Why it didn't work with flux design...